# if $f > g$ for all $x$ on $[a,b]$, is the $\int f > \int g$ on $[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

I know that there is a theorem saying that if $f \geq g$ on $[a,b]$, then $\int f \geq \int g$, but I am wondering if we only have $f > g$, can we absolutely get a result of $\int f > \int g$.

From the proof, it seems that it is possible that if $f > g$, $\int f = \int g$, but this does not make intuitive sense to me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1816160/comparison-between-integrals
If the inequality of the functions is strict, then so is the inequality of the integrals, provided $a \neq b$ so $[a,b]$ has positive measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $f$ be 1 at 0 and 0 elsewhere. Let $g$ be 0 everywhere. Both have integral zero.

However, you seem to be asking if $f(x) > g(x)$ for all $x.$ In this case, $h(x) = f(x) - g(x) >0$ for all $x.$ Yes this does have positive integral.

Let $h_{n} = h I_{x>1/n}.$

The functions $h_n$ converge to $h$ monotonically upwards. If $h_n$ has integral $0$ then $h < 1/n$ on a set of full measure. If they all have integral zero, then $h=0$ on a set of full measure as an intersection (countable) of sets of full measure.

This cannot happen so $\int h \geq \int h_n >0$ for some $n.$