# Refutation of claim of cyclic relationship between distribution functions

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, measure-theory

Based on [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2739767/140308): Is the refutation of the following claim correct? I'm trying to see if I understand antkam correctly and if antkam is right.

> Claim:

It is possible to have $F_{i}(t)$s be unknown CDFs and $G_{i}(t)$s be known pdfs s.t.

$$F_{1}'(t)=\dfrac{G_{1}(t)}{(1-F_{2})F_{3}}$$
$$F_{2}'(t)=\dfrac{G_{2}(t)}{(1-F_{3})F_{1}}$$
$$F_{3}'(t)=\dfrac{G_{3}(t)}{(1-F_{1})F_{2}}$$

> Refutation:

1. We must have all denominators less than 1 or all denominators equal to 1.
2. We rule out the latter because this contradicts the non-decreasing property of CDFs. It remains to rule out the former.
3. $$\frac{G_{1}(t)}{(1-F_{2})F_{3}} > G_{1}(t) \iff G_1(t) = 0 \iff 1 = (1-F_{2})F_{3}$$
4. We cannot have that $$\int_{\mathbb R} \dfrac{G_{1}(t)}{(1-F_{2})F_{3}} dt > \int_{\mathbb R} G_{1}(t) dt$$ because $$1 = \int_{\mathbb R} \dfrac{G_{1}(t)}{(1-F_{2})F_{3}} dt = \int_{\mathbb R} G_{1}(t) dt $$, but we do have that from 3 and because [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1816673/140308).

For #1, must we? If $F_3(t_a) = 1$, then I was thinking $G_2(t_a) = 0$?

For #2, what if the union of such t's has measure zero? Do we need to use Lebesgue measure?

Comment: You only have $\;\int f  \ge \int g$.

Comment: You can come up with far simpler examples.  Just use characteristic/indicator functions.

Comment: Either I'm missing something (quite possible), or the title of the question is quite a long way from having anything to do with the actual crux of the question....

Comment: @AaronMontgomery I forgot to edit the title. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For #1, must we?

Yes. Suppose that $F_3(a) = 1$; then (as you noted in the comments here) $G_2(a) = 0$ in order to have any hope of these equations making sense. In fact, this implies that $F_3(t) = 1$ and $G_2(t) = 0$ for all $t \geq a$. Having $G_2(t) = 0$ on $[a, \infty)$ implies that $F_2(t) = 1$ on $[a, \infty)$ since we must have $\lim_{t \to \infty} F_2(t) = 1$ and $F_2(t) - F_2(a) = \int_a^t G_2(s) \, \textrm d s$. Then we repeat the above argument to show that $F_2(t) = 1$ on $[a, \infty)$ implies that $F_1(t) = 1$ on $[a, \infty)$.

> For #2, what if the union of such t's has measure zero?

If by "such $t$'s" you mean $\{t :F_i(t) = 1\}$, then this set is either empty or of infinite measure. Since $F_i(t)$ is a nondecreasing function bounded above by $1$, then $F_i(a) = 1$ implies that $F_i(t) = 1$ for all $t \geq a$.

Comment: For #1 Please elaborate. It is contradictory for them to be all 1. But why not 1 of them is 1 and the rest are less than 1?  (ETA: Oh I forgot: if one denominator is 1 then the rest of the denominators are zero. I was thinking to define the G's to take the value of zero to avoid having the $F_i$'s be undefined ) For #2 Ok. Thanks, Aaron Montgomery!

Comment: Ah, I see -- I was too hasty. Let me think about it, and if I don't have a good response, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: I've edited my response; hopefully I haven't missed the mark a second time, but please let me know if I have.

Comment: You mean $F_3(t) = 1$ and $G_2(t)=0$ instead of $F_3(t) = G_2(t) = 0$?

Comment: Yep, thanks for the catch. I'll edit again.

Comment: I think you should say 'Good catch' then I'm the one who thanks you or something. Idk. Thanks. Another: $F_2(t) - F_2(a) = \int_a^t G_2(s) \, \textrm d s$? Another: How did you get that (whichever is right between $s$ or $t$)?

Comment: Last is optional. I get why $F_2(t)=1$ now after I made a simple discrete random variable example. Lol. Thanks! Happy 4th week of Easter ^-^